# How to get uri_for with webapp2 in unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to unit test a handler with webapp2 and am running into what has to be just a stupid little error.

I'd like to be able to use webapp2.uri_for in the test, but I can't seem to do that:

```
    def test_returns_200_on_home_page(self):
        response = main.app.get_response(webapp2.uri_for('index'))
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_int)
```

If I just do `main.app.get_response('/')` it works just fine.

The exception received is:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 318, in run
    testMethod()
  File "tests.py", line 27, in test_returns_200_on_home_page
    webapp2.uri_for('index')
  File "/Users/.../webapp2_example/lib/webapp2.py", line 1671, in uri_for
    return request.app.router.build(request, _name, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/.../webapp2_example/lib/webapp2_extras/local.py", line 173, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Users/.../webapp2_example/lib/webapp2_extras/local.py", line 136, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError('no object bound to %s' % self.__name__)
RuntimeError: no object bound to request
```

Is there some silly setup I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the only option is to set a dummy request just to be able to create URIs for the test:

```
def test_returns_200_on_home_page(self):
    // Set a dummy request just to be able to use uri_for().
    req = webapp2.Request.blank('/')
    req.app = main.app
    main.app.set_globals(app=main.app, request=req)

    response = main.app.get_response(webapp2.uri_for('index'))
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_int)
```

Never use `set_globals()` outside of tests. Is is called by the WSGI application to set the active app and request in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @moraes. I'll give it a try when I get home from work. I really like webapp2 by the way, thanks for sharing it with us!

Comment: That doesn't quite seem to be it either. now I receive:   File "/Users/.../webapp2_example/lib/webapp2.py", line 1671, in uri_for
    return request.app.router.build(request, _name, args, kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'router'

Comment: Indeed, not that easy. I corrected the snippet; hope it works now.

Comment: perfect, I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

`webapp2.uri_for()` assumes that you are in a web request context and it fails because it cannot find the `request` object.

Instead of working around this you could think of your application as a black box and call it using literal URIs, like `'/'` as you mention it. After all, you want to simulate a normal web request, and a web browser will also use URIs and not internal routing shortcuts.

Comment: I see your point, however, it violates the 'DRY' principal to put the full url anywhere more than once. If the url changes, it's much more of a pain (and error prone) to change everywhere it is literally referenced rather than changing the url route declaration and being done

Comment: In fact, https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#extended-routes points out that DRY is part of the motivation for improving webapp, "avoiding hardcoded URIs in the app code and templates"